# Flink KeyedProcessFunction not sending data to subsequent steps

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using a Sort function in my pipeline

1. Reads the data from Kafka Topic
2. Removes the Duplicates
3. Sorts them based on timestamp
4. Writes them back to Kafka Topic.

When i run this locally every thing works fine (How ever in my local test i am not reading the data from kafka but generating the records using a Dummy generator and in the final step printing the records instead of sending them to Kafka.

When i execute the same in EMR then i see data flowing through into the Sort Operator how ever nothing is coming out of it.

Here is my Sort Function

```
public class SortMessages  extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Message, Message> {

    private ValueState<PriorityQueue<Message>> queueState = null;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SortMessages.class);

    private Boolean debugFlag = Boolean.FALSE;
    
    

    public SortMessages(Boolean debugFlag){
        this.debugFlag = debugFlag;
        logger.info(".SortMessages() : ====== queueState={}"+queueState);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<PriorityQueue<Message>> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                // state name
                "sorted-messages",
                // type information of state
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<PriorityQueue<Message>>() {
                }));
        queueState = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
        logger.info(".open() : queueState ={}"+queueState);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(Message event, Context context, Collector<Message> out) throws Exception {
        TimerService timerService = context.timerService();
        //logger.info("================================================================");
        //logger.info(".processElement() : event ={}"+event);
        logger.info(".processElement() : Current Key =["+context.getCurrentKey()+"] Event Timestamp=["+event.getTimestamp()+"] Context Timestamp ={}"+context.timestamp()+" Watermark ={}"+timerService.currentWatermark());
        //logger.info(".processElement() : Watermark ={}"+timerService.currentWatermark());
        if (context.timestamp() > timerService.currentWatermark()) {
            PriorityQueue<Message> queue = queueState.value();
            if (queue == null) {
                queue = new PriorityQueue<>(10);
            }
            queue.add(event);
            queueState.update(queue);
            timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(event.getTimestamp());
            logger.info(".processElement() : Queue Size ={}"+queue.size());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext context, Collector<Message> out) throws Exception {
        logger.info(".onTimer() : ===========> onTimer Called <===============" );
        PriorityQueue<Message> queue = queueState.value();
        Long watermark = context.timerService().currentWatermark();
        //logger.info(".onTimer() : watermark ={}",watermark);
        Message head = queue.peek();
        logger.info(".onTimer() : watermark = "+watermark+" Head="+ (head!=null ? head.getTimestamp() : "null"));

        //List<Message> queueTmp = queueState.value();

        while (head != null && head.getTimestamp() <= watermark) {
            out.collect(head);
            queue.remove(head);
            head = queue.peek();
        }
    }

}
```

And here is how i am processing the data stream.

```
DataStream<NopMessage> dedupedMessages = messages
                    .keyBy(value -> value.getHashCode())
                    .flatMap(new Deduplicate()).name("Remove the Duplicates");

            DataStream<NopMessage> dedupedSortedMessages = dedupedMessages
                    .keyBy(value -> value.getHashCode())
                    .process(new SortMessages(false)).name("Sort Messages on Timestamp");

dedupedSortedMessages.addSink(kafkaProducer).name("Send Messages to Kafka Topic");

streamingExecutionEnv.execute("Dedupe Sorting Job_"+Calendar.getInstane().getTimeInMillis());
```

And in EMR Flink UI i don't see any watermarks for any of the subtasks.

When i load the Data from Kafka Topic i am assigning a Custom Watermark Assigner.

```
DataStream<Message> messages = streamingExecutionEnv.addSource(
                    new CustomFlinkKafkaConsumer<Message>(
                            sourceTopics,
                            new ConsumerDeserializationSchemaCSV(),
                            getConsumerProps()
                    )
            ).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                    new MessageTSWAssigner()
                   
            ).name("Consume Data from Kafka Topic");
```

And my Custom Watermark Timestamp Assigner just retrieves the timestamp from the message and uses it as event time.

```
public class MessageTSWAssigner extends AscendingTimestampExtractor<Message> {

    @Override
    public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Message element) {
        return element.getTimestamp();
    }

}
```

If i remove the Sorting from the pipeline then data is flowing to destination kafka topics as expected.

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: Is the watermark advancing in the operator doing the sort? Perhaps something is holding back the watermark, such as an idle Kafka partition.

Comment: I checked the logs and the log statement in the constructor for SortMessages() is not getting logged. In Flink UI it is showing 3 Tasks: 1) Source: Custom Source -> Consume Data from Kafka Topic  2) Remove the Duplicates 3) Sort Messages on TImestmp -> Sink: Send Messages to Kafka Topic.  And Data is flowing into Task 3 (i can see 150K Records send to Task3) .How ever as you said the watermark might not be advancing in the operator.

Comment: There are no idle partitions in the topic i am consuming from, and the Prior operator is getting the data from the topic. Are you referring to the target topic i am writing to ? How does it affect if the DataStream doesn't have data for all the topic partitions ?

Comment: I was referring to the consumer topic. I still suspect the watermarking, but I'm not sure of the cause.